# Nginx server name regex allow dash

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a site, running on nginx, when comes to the server name i come across some problem regarding the regex, as i know nginx is using Perl Compatible Regular Expressions(PCRE).

Now my server name:

`server_name "~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.parentdomain\.com$";`

So it only allows case like the following:

`abc.parentdomain.com`

But i want to allow dash in my subdomain, like

`abc-def.parentdomain.com`

I tried to modify the pattern, but no luck

`server_name "~^(?<subdomain>\w\-+)\.parentdomain\.com$";`

`server_name "~^(?<subdomain>\w+\-)\.parentdomain\.com$";`

`server_name "~^(?<subdomain>\w+)(\-)\.parentdomain\.com$";`

Is there something wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply putting one after another won't turn them into alternatives – it'll just make a sequence. You're allowing a series of word characters, and *then* a dash. For example `subdom-.example.com`.

You need to explicitly mark these classes as alternatives, e.g. `(\w|-)` or `[\w-]`.

```
server_name "~^(?<subdomain>(\w|-)+)\.parentdomain\.com$";
server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[\w-]+)\.parentdomain\.com$";
```

*(Think about it: if PCRE automatically turned everything into alternatives, then having the word "parentdomain" in the regex wouldn't actually allow "parentdomain" – it would allow either "p" or "a" or "r" or "e" or...)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow dashes **between** word character:

```
server_name "~^(?<subdomain>\w+(?:-\w+)*)\.parentdomain\.com$";
```

Where

`(?:-\w+)*` is a [non capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that allows a dash followed by some word characters, the group may appear 0 or more times. It doesn't match consecutive dashes.

It matches:

- `subdomain.parentdomain.com`
- `sub-domain.parentdomain.com`
- `sub-do-main.parentdomain.com`
- and so on...

but not

- `sub--domain.parentdomain.com`
- `-subdomain.parentdomain.com`
- `subdomain-.parentdomain.com`
- `---.parentdomain.com`